# Facebook-Like without users logged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

In my physical store, I have a few tablets available in which I use to obtain shoppers' email addresses. I'll leave them up on a simple web page where they just enter their email address to join my companies email mailing list.

I would like to add the ability for these individuals to also 'Like' my company on Facebook without actually logging into Facebook. My thoughts are that they will not want to log into Facebook via a shared machine due to security concerns and also the added time to log on will deter them from even adding their email address to begin with.

Here is what i am thinking...I was hoping to send the 'Like' update to their account based on the email address that they provided without actually loggin on. Can this be achieved?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

No, the user must be logged in to send requests to facebook on their behalf

Comment: Is there a Facebook component that allows them to 'Like' the page by adding their credentials but doesn't log them in? I realize I'm reaching but I wish for them not to log in...

Comment: I'm afraid not, all the facebook requests requires an authentication token to be valid, and the only way to get this token is by completing the login handshake with facebook, aka logging them in. Sorry :(